# Switching from PHP's mysql extension to PDO. Extend class to reduce lines of code

Tags: php, constructor, pdo

So this is something I've been meaning to get to grips with for ages. Converting a few small (single-file) applications to PDO. I can use PDO, connect to a database and run queries, all working.

But each time I initialise a new PDO, I'm also having to run
`setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
Yeah it's only one line but one day I might need to add further stuff in there. To me it would seem better to somehow extend the PDO class in a way that can include that line so I can just start my DB connection with a single line. Creating my own class, even if only adding a single line of code at this stage, keeps me future-proofed if I ever decide to add anything else in the future.

I've found something like this...

```
class myPDO extends PDO {
    public function __construct($dsn, $user=null, $pass=null, $options=null) {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

// THEN A SIMPLE 1 LINER TO CONNECT - USING TRY/CATCH AS WELL OF COURSE
$pdo_conn = new myPDO($cfg['pdo_dsn'], $cfg['pdo_user'], $cfg['pdo_pass'], $cfg['pdo_options']);
```

When extending the class I assume I don't actually need to re-create the constructor.
Is there a way I can integrate my `$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` into my class **without** re-creating the constructor function?

I'm just getting started with PHP's class syntax so this will be a really basic question for someone but it will answer a few other questions for me at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to extend from PDO here. What you want is a central place in your application that is creating the PDO object. You can then do the changes you like over time (e.g. integrating some configuration file/system) and extend then centrally.

One thing is that you create a class for that, let's call it `PdoFactory`:

```
class PdoFactory
{
     /**
      * @return PDO
      */
     public function buildPdo() {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn = 'xyz', $user = 'abc', $pass = '', $options  = '');
        if ($pdoException = true) {
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return $pdo;
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
$factory = new PdoFactory();
$pdo = $factory->buildPdo();
```

As you can see, this is very easy to use. You can even put the place where you create the `PdoFactory` apart from the place where you invoke the `buildPdo()` function.

Also this makes it more clear that you are dealing with two different things here: First creating the Pdo object (encapsulated into a class of it's own) and the Pdo object itself which is just for accessing the database.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! Question... my db config parameters are stored in an array. I don't really want to hard-code them in the class - although it's just as easy to change as in my config array. I realise I could pass these as params to the `PdoFactory()` class instantiation. But are there any other options to have them brought in to the PdoFactory/buildPdo functions? Constants are a bad idea as they are then accessible throughout my application, as are globals. I suppose I could global the array at the start of the class, then unset them from globals at the end?

Comment: @batfastad: The code is meant exemplary. You can pass your configuration array to the object with it's constructor for example (which would need to be added naturally as right now the `__construct` function is not yet defined). Then inside the `buildPdo` function you read from that array.

Comment: I see, so I pass the array as a param to my class def which is then passed in turn to the buildPdo function so the `new PDO()` bit can access the data? Also what do you mean by need to be added "naturally"?

Comment: Because it's not there yet. So it needs to be added otherwise it will be still not there yet :) That's all. ;) Naturally I could have left the word "Naturally" out :) Because it won't work otherwise so should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Oh right, thanks ;) So rather than extending the PDO class, this is a wrapper. Now should/could I put my try-catch block within this class? Or should I do that outside in the parent code?

Comment: @batfastad: Always in the "parent" code. You didn't want to extend PDO to call itself bit within a try-catch block, didn't you? (just curious and just keep asking)

Comment: I'm not sure if I did want to do that. I'd just like to be repeating as little code on each page as possible so from that point of view it would make sense to do try/catch within the class. But if it's "better" for it to be done in the parent code then fine. +1 and answered!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16012/discussion-between-hakra-and-batfastad)

Comment: No in that case you have a global exception handler. In case an exception is thrown but not catched, you return a 500 (Internal Server Error) page to the client. Also you log that and get an email from the live site so you know everything is running smooth. Also you learn that way which errors actually appear and you can then improve the code and probably one or two try/catch blocks here and there.

Comment: A custom exception handler sounds like a very good thing, and I will be doing all sorts of logging of errors. I'm a procedural guy and up until now haven't really explored exceptions. So if I want to output a friendly error to the user (using my site's template for example), would that be done by my custom exception handler? Or in my catch block on each page?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I see it, is that you are hard-coding a particular error level into your application. What if you're in development and you want everything? What if you decide you want to change the level for a particular application? It would be much better to keep it as a parameter you set after the fact, or, if you're bent on subclassing it, pass an error level in as a constructor argument.

Comment: Fair enough, I see where you're coming from. Doing it this way at least I can change the error reporting in just one place, rather than in every occurrence of PDO class instantiation. Surely I will always want the errors to be triggered, then I can log them and tune the display in my exception/error handlers? And that's a question I've got lined up for another time.